# Android: positioning an admob ad

Tags: android, layout, admob

I am having problems positioning my admob ad in my app. With the code below, I get an error that says
`error parsing XML: unbound prefix`

I can't seem to fix it. What am i doing wrong? Is there another way to position an ad?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <com.admob.android.ads.AdView
   android:id="@+id/ads"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   myapp:backgroundColor="#000000"
   myapp:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF"
   myapp:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC"
   myapp:refreshInterval="10"
   android:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Just change `myapp:` to `admobsdk:`

Comment: am I see something wrong? Where is "myapp" in the code?

Comment: `xmlns:admobsdk="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/joke.content"`

Comment: In your AdView, you wrote something like `myapp:`, did you see it?

Answer (score 2):

The compiler does not understand your `myapp:`

Please use `admobsdk:` instead.

See the code example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:admobsdk="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/joke.content"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/photo" android:src="@drawable/joker"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content">
                <TextView android:id="@+id/title" android:text=""
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="24sp" android:textColor="@color/css_a"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"></TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">
                <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="" android:id="@+id/content"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />
        </ScrollView>

        <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                <Button android:text="下一篇" android:id="@+id/next"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
                        android:textSize="22sp"></Button>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <com.admob.android.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/ad"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" admobsdk:backgroundColor="#000000"
                admobsdk:textColor="#FFFFFF" admobsdk:refreshInterval="60"
                admobsdk:keywords="笑话" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                admobsdk:testing="false" admobsdk:isGoneWithoutAd="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Please make sure you have this line in the previous code:

```
xmlns:admobsdk="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/joke.content"
```

Does your attrs.xml(in res/values folder) file look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
    <resources>
      <declare-styleable name="com.admob.android.ads.AdView">
        <attr name="backgroundColor" format="color" /> 
        <attr name="primaryTextColor" format="color" /> 
        <attr name="secondaryTextColor" format="color" /> 
        <attr name="keywords" format="string" /> 
        <attr name="refreshInterval" format="integer" /> 
      </declare-styleable>
    </resources>
```

If not, create an xml file names attrs.xml in your res/values folder and copy this code into it.

`joke.content` is your package name. Remember to change it to your package name.

Comment: Hi, sorry I dont quite understand what you are saying.

Comment: `myapp` or `admobsdk` is here: `xmlns:admobsdk="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/joke.content"`

Comment: That is the namespace which I copied from a worked code. I also update another solution in my answer. Please see at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you sir. You are my hero!

Comment: That helped a lot. I am getting multiline errors now. No resource found in joke.content

Comment: `joke.content` is your package name. Please change it to your package name. Sorry for just copying and did not mention you about this.

Comment: I've just updated the mention about package name in the answer too.

Comment: @Mich what SDK version are you using?  This answer is for a very old version of the AdMob SDK (v4.0.4 and below I believe).  If you're on a later version, you don't need an attrs.xml file, and you should check out Pablo's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You missed this line on the LinearLayout:
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"

Take a look to this url:

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/banner_xml